# Combinational algorithm for Excel VBA

Tags: excel, algorithm, vba, combinations

Let's say that I have a set of items as the one below:

```
Item    Units
Apples    5
Pears     5
Carrots   1
Oranges   4
```

And I have six persons to whom I can give these items. Let's call them:

```
Mr. A
Mr. B
Mr. C
Mr. D
Mr. E
Mr. F
```

I would need an Excel VBA code that retrieves me all the potential combinations of sharing the items presented above to the different persons. Please note that (i) order is not important and (ii) one person may have more than one unit of the same item.

In order to report this information I was thinking of a structure similar to that presented below:

```
                          Mr A                                 Mr B                   ...
             Apples  Pears  Carrots  Oranges       Apples  Pears  Carrots  Oranges    ...
Scenario 1     1       0       1        2             2      2       0        0       ...
Scenario 2     1       0       1        1             2      2       0        0       ...
...
```

I know that the number of combinations will be huge, but don't mind about computing requirements.

I've been trying to figure out the algorithm, but have not been able to achieve it.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you probably know this already, but you'll receive way more help if you **post the code you've tried**. In case you haven't already, read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you don't provide your coding efforts and where they are failing, the question will most likely be closed.

Comment: The issue is that I've previously implemented similar combinational algorithms just through Excel formulas. However, in this case I do not know how to tackle the fact that I may have more than one unit given to the same person, neither have I seen any previous post in which this issue in presented.

Comment: What is the maximum number of each item one person can have? And is there a maximum total of all items each person can have? If no to those then the answer is there are an infinite number of possible combinations and therefore and endless loop.

Comment: The maximum number of each item each person can have is limited by the number of units of that item. For instance, Mr. A could have 5 apples, while the other persons would not have any. There is not any limit in what relates to the maximum number of total items a person may have.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use Mr A and Mr B for testing and there are 360 different scenarios.

```
Sub distr_list()
Dim apple_a, apple_b

Count = 1

Cells(Count, 4) = "apple_a"
Cells(Count, 5) = "pear_a"
Cells(Count, 6) = "carrot_a"
Cells(Count, 7) = "orange_a"

Cells(Count, 9) = "apple_b"
Cells(Count, 10) = "pear_b"
Cells(Count, 11) = "carrot_b"
Cells(Count, 12) = "orange_b"

For apple_a = 0 To 5
For apple_b = 0 To 5

For pear_a = 0 To 5
For pear_b = 0 To 5

For carrot_a = 0 To 1
For carrot_b = 0 To 1

For orange_a = 0 To 4
For orange_b = 0 To 4


 If apple_a + apple_b = 5 Then
    If pear_a + pear_b = 5 Then
        If carrot_a + carrot_b = 1 Then
            If orange_a + orange_b = 4 Then

    Cells(Count + 1, 4) = apple_a
    Cells(Count + 1, 5) = pear_a
    Cells(Count + 1, 6) = carrot_a
    Cells(Count + 1, 7) = orange_a

    Cells(Count + 1, 9) = apple_b
    Cells(Count + 1, 10) = pear_b
    Cells(Count + 1, 11) = carrot_b
    Cells(Count + 1, 12) = orange_b

    Count = Count + 1

 End If
 End If
 End If
 End If

Next
Next
Next
Next
Next
Next
Next
Next

End Sub
```

You can apply the same logic for the rest.